# Coding challenge involving integer pairs

Tags: c++

I was presented with a coding challenge:

> Given two integer arrays (in this case, the two given arrays have the same length of 6). And a target of 24. Find two pairs of numbers from those 2 arrays whose sums are closest to the target.

I kinda find it lengthy. How can I improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
void which_no(int x, int arr01[6], int arr02[6]) {
    if (x <= 6) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[0] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (x > 6 && x < 13) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[1] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 7:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 8:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 9:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 10:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 11:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 12:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (x > 12 && x < 19) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[2] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 13:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 14:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 15:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 16:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 17:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 18:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (x > 18 && x < 25) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[3] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 19:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 20:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 21:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 22:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 23:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 24:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (x > 24 && x < 31) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[4] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 25:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 26:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 27:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 28:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 29:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 30:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (x > 30 && x < 37) {
        std::cout << "(" << arr01[5] << ",";
        switch (x) {
        case 31:
            std::cout << arr02[0] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 32:
            std::cout << arr02[1] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 33:
            std::cout << arr02[2] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 34:
            std::cout << arr02[3] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 35:
            std::cout << arr02[4] << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 36:
            std::cout << arr02[5] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr01[] = { 5,-8,6,7,-10,9 };
    int arr02[] = { 1,3,10,20,-5,6 };
    int arr_sum[36]; int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            arr_sum[x] = arr01[i] + arr02[j];
            ++x;
        }
    }
    int arr_diff[36];
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
        if (arr_sum[i] > 24) {
            arr_diff[i] = arr_sum[i] - 24;
        }
        else {
            arr_diff[i] = 24 - arr_sum[i];
        }
    }
    int min=arr_diff[0],min_n=1;
    for (int j = 1; j < 36; ++j) {
        if (min > arr_diff[j]) {
            min = arr_diff[j];
            min_n = j+1;
        }
    }
    int s_min = arr_diff[0], s_min_n = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < 36; ++j) {
        if (s_min > arr_diff[j]&&arr_diff[j]>min) {
            s_min = arr_diff[j];
            s_min_n = j + 1;
        }
    }
    which_no(min_n, arr01, arr02);
    which_no(s_min_n, arr01, arr02);

}
```

Comment: What if both arrays had 100 elements or 1000 elements?  That's how you should approach the problem.  Hardcoding a solution for 6 elements is not a good solution.

Comment: Let me confirm again. So "From two given arrays(`A` and `B`)  we need to pick two numbers (`a` ∈ `A` and `b` ∈ `B`). Such that sum(`a+b`) is close to 24."

Comment: Advice -- These online coding questions are notorious for asking questions that have very naive solutions that work for small input, but fail due to "time out" issues (the solution took too long due to the size of the input).  The goal of these questions is to see if you can come up with a non-naive solution, i.e. think outside the box (usually get a handle on data structures and algorithms).

Comment: Oh, and this: `for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)` --  Strive to never write solutions with these types of nested loops.  This is almost always never going to work.  Again, if you had 1,000 items, you will be looping a million times!  Ten thousand items, that is 100 million loop iterations!  That is an example of naive solutions that only work for small input, and will time-out on larger sets of input.  This is exactly what those online quizzes are testing for.

Comment: There are several mods possible in your code. The switch statements in `which_no()` can be trivially replaced with oneliners, if you simply use `x` (or an expression using it) as an array index.That will help with readability, and make your code much shorter. The multiple loops in `main()` can be combined quite easily into one.   I won't write an answer to do that though - you'll learn more of use by thinking about how to simplify the code, than you will if someone just gives you the answer.  Having magic numbers like `6` and `36` littered in your code is bad practice, and also easily removed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is misleading to say you always have to generalize. Imagine I have some kind of problem involving integers. It would make little sense to try to generalize to complex numbers, although it might be possible and might work fine. If I don't need it, I would only waste a lot of time with the generalization. If I am given a task with 6 elements I will solve for 6 elements unless I am aware of a generalized version of the problem, or unless I expect having to solve the problem for different number of elements. But if 6 elements is all my problem, 6 elements solution is fine.

Comment: As my comment suggested, many, if not all of the questions given by the online coding challenge sites will always give the easy case as an example, thus goad the question solver into giving solutions like the one given here.  This is for them to be aware of this tactic, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is `O(n*n)`, due to the usage of the nested `for` loop.  For just 6 elements, this may not be such a big deal, but if the number of elements are in the hundreds or thousands, the comments in the main section explains why this solution is not really viable.

Thus a better (probably not the best, but somewhat better) should be worked out.  This requires some manipulation of one of the arrays.  Here is a proposed solution:

The "goal amount" is the integer you want to find the pair of numbers closest to it (in your case, this value is `24`).

1. Sort the second array of numbers in ascending order
2. Keep a "global minimum" value, which holds the current smallest distance between the goal amount and the pair of numbers you're testing.
3. Iterate through the first array.  For each iteration, subtract the current value in the first array from the goal amount (call this value the "search value").  For example, `search_value = 24 - arr01[i]` if `i` is the index of the current item.
4. Given that the items in the second array are now sorted, using a binary search (i.e. `std::lower_bound`) can be used to find the item in the second array closest to the search value found in step 3.
5. If the value found (call this the "found_value") using `std::lower_bound` added to `arr01[i]`, less the goal amount, is smaller than the global minimum distance, then the new minimum distance is the pair `[arr01[i], found_value]`.

The runtime of doing this, given `n` elements is:

1. `O(n * log(n))` -- for the initial sort (use `std::sort`), plus
2. `O(n * log(n))` -- for the linear traversal through the first array and for the binary search.

So if you add all this up, the algorithmic complexity should be `O(n * log(n))` (someone correct me if this analysis is not correct).

Thus, when given a large amount of input, the runtime of doing things this way will outweigh using an `O(n*n)` solution (which is the one you came up with -- read my comments about the nested `for` loop).

For example, a thousand numbers would be `1000 * 10 == 10 000` using the logarithmic runtime, as opposed to `1000 * 1000 == 1 000 000` iterations using the `O(n*n)` runtime.

---

Here is a probable solution (disclosure: not tested 100%), that captures the steps above:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

int arr01[] = { 5,-8,6,7,-10,9 };
int arr02[] = { 1,3,10,20,-5,6 };

int main()
{
    int goal = 24;  // Our goal amount

    // The final pair of numbers 
    std::pair<int, int> answer;

    // 1. Sort the second array
    std::sort(std::begin(arr02), std::end(arr02));

    // 2. Initialize the minimum distance found so far 
    int min_distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // 3. Iterate through the first array 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(arr01); ++i)
    {
        // This is the search value
        int search_value = goal - arr01[i];

        // 4. Get value in our sorted list that is closest to the search value
        int *pClosest = std::lower_bound(std::begin(arr02), std::end(arr02), search_value);

        // 5. check if the distance is smaller than our current minimum 
        int test_distance = abs(arr01[i] + *pClosest - goal);
        if ( test_distance < min_distance)
        {
            // Yes, so our new answer is the pair we just tested,
            // and we set the minimum distance to the smaller distance
            answer = std::make_pair(arr01[i], *pClosest);
            min_distance = test_distance;
        }
    }

    // Output results 
    std::cout << answer.first << " " << answer.second;
}
```

Output:

```
5 20
```